# Translating gas and storage units to XTZ

Tags: storage, fees, gas

I'm interested in translating the gas and storage costs I get in response from the node after an operation into XTZ prices. Where could I find this information online?

Answer (score 3):

Storage price is 0.25tez per kilobyte. Gas units are not directly charged, see https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/psa-do-not-quote-gas-cost-in-tez/1618.